# How to to experience fully immmersive VR?

Tags: science-based, computers, virtual-reality

I'm talking about full BCI, altered electrical feedback from brain to computer you'd need,technical issues.

Comment: Can you give the term BCI stands for?  It's not like it's  brain surgery... well... okay... it's technically neuroscience which you need for brain surge... and basic grammar to use the full term when introducing an acronym.

Comment: Brain computer interface

Comment: How to to experience fully immmersive VR: Step 1. Browse Amazon / BangGood / BestBuy / NewEgg for BCI-based VR device. Step 2. Select device. Step 3. Order device. Step 4. Unpack device and set it up. Step 5. Download VR game / VR travel scenario / other VR title possibly NSFW. Step 6. Experience fully immersive VR.

Comment: You are already in a fully immersive VR.  Nothing your brain perceives as reality is reality, it is just the electrochemical impulses entering your brain from your nervous system.  Any correlation between those impulses and what really exists is purely hypothetical.    ...or from the opposite approach, a real BCI VR will be so realistic that it cannot be differentiated in any way from the natural impulses received from your nervous system.  Therefore the easiest way to experience such VR is to live in the real world which is quantitatively and qualitatively identical to that BCIVR experience.

Comment: if i wanted listen to armchair philosopher i'd go on reddit. This is not even what i asked for

Comment: Fair enough, but to be fair, the technology you are asking about is so far from our current level that even the best answer is going to be pure speculation.  We can't even fix paralysis yet which has to be much easier than replacing the entire neurological stack which is what is needed for full immersion.  I stand by the second half of my comment above; real life is as close as your going to get to immersive VR at least for the foreseeable future.